# How to import css root constant from another css file

Tags: html, css, variables, reference, constants

I have two css files **constants.css** and **main.css**

In my **constants.css** file  `root: { --primaryColor: red;  }`

In my **main.css** file  `.example { background-color: var(primaryColor); }`

Expected behaviour is **red color** as background-color in . example class, but it's not working.

I tried `@include 'constants.css'` and `@include url('constants.css')`, but it didn't helped.

So my question is that how to include root constants from another css file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

define your css variables in your  constants.css

```css
:root {
  --green: #119955;
}
```

then import it using `@import './constants.css;` in your main.css file.
and use your variables

```css
@import './constants.css';

body {
  background-color: var(--green);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to force applying the style by using `!important` or it would not work at all.

```
@import './constants.css';

.example {
    background-color: var(primaryColor) !important;
}
```